# Relay controller with IO expander

Tags: arduino-uno

found this
http://www.zevendevelopment.com/relayexpander.html
I was looking to control 48 relays in sequential order with external controls for duration and frequency. How do I properly communicate to the boards? Sorry new to this setup.

Comment: Looks like you communicate via the [IOExpander](http://www.zevendevelopment.com/ioexpander.html) board.

Comment: Their IO expander gets controlled via Serial (UART). From there all the relay expanders are controlled. Have you already bought these boards?

Comment: I guess what I’m really saying is I’m not clear on how to properly code this. I have not bought these boards yet but they seem like the perfect solution. Would you recommend anything else?